# SSRS 2012 --- Report Snapshot Issue

Tags: sql-server, report, ssrs-2012

I have a report which takes fairly large time to run. So, I have created Snapshot for the report.
Report Snapshot feature requires all the parameters should have default value.
On providing all parameter a default value will fulfill the purpose of snapshot.

But, If user wants to run the report manually, then with the default parameters report runs automatically. Is there anyway to stop the report from running automatically and let user enter value for parameters?

Comment: How are the users running the report? Because they should be able to enter parameters value in report browser, in internet explorer or if it is in your application you should provide a way for the users to choose/enter values for those parameters. Alternatively I would save different snapshots with different parameters default values and allow the users to select the snapshot they want to run; also providing a custom option for the user to enter values for the parameters and informing then that this option will take long to generate.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible if all parameters have default value then SSRS Report is populated automatically. Make at least one Parameter which does not have default value .

Comment: Able to get a workaround, Made one of the parameter to select default value from 2:00 AM to 2:15 AM. Shapshot is schedule to run at 2:01 AM.and for the rest of day that parameter remains empty, and this allows user to select parameter and report not runs automatically.